# A Simple utility to monitor web application performance

Tags: java, performance, web

My system setup is like: Application A takes requests from outside world and communicates with the backend REST apis. REST api also communicates with mysql database.

My requirement is to have a tool from which I can just monitor the resource usage and may be the performance of the web server. I want to have graphs for the resource usage which means I need historical data otherwise I would have just used the windows task manager to see the resource usage.

This means I do not need any load generator(that will be done by the Application A) just a resource monitor.

I googled and found tools like appdynamics, Nagios, munin but not sure if they are what I need. I haven't done performance testing earlier so there's lot of confusion.

Just looking for some guidance.

Thanks

Comment: How you want to use it?

Comment: [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) is one option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about "run tool-get result" the best option - [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html). It's free in test environment. You need to pay only for some features in production. It's much better than old VisualVM.

You can write a data to file using [Flight Recorder](http://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-5/jfr-runtime-guide/run.htm#CHDIDCHG). You can setup start point and duration. You just need to start your application like this:

`-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:StartFlightRecording=duration=60s,filename=myrecording.jfr`

Comment: Thanks. I find this useful enough for my case but is there any way to save the data so that I can see it and graph it at later point of time.

Comment: @user3275095, you can add vote or accepted my answer, if it helps you :) Also, I added more information how to save data.

Comment: I usually downvote answers to questions that are clearly off topic.

Comment: @DavidS, it would be more productive if you say why it's off topic?

Comment: Good point, I will do both. See point 4 in this [off topic list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I sometimes comment on off topic questions to provide help; I just don't bother posting answers because the questions should be closed or deleted anyhow.

Comment: @DavidS, year, I got your point. I just can't understand there is my mistake :)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your most recent comment, but it sounds like your don't understand your mistake, so I will try to explain again. @user3275095's post is off topic because it's a tool request, which is [off topic according to the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Answers to off topic questions are also off topic. We should not post answers to off topic questions, because it will only encourage more off topic questions. For the same reason, we should downvote answers to off topic questions.

Comment: I think you are misusing the down vote privilege. I totally agree on down-voting off topic questions, but answer to off-topic questions as well? Unless the answer is misleading, from http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down, should not discourage anyone to provide input.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, @Jimmy. We're going to discourage asking off-topic questions, but encourage answering them? How would that possibly be a good thing?